# Uploading images to different folders in localhost

Tags: php, android

i want to add images to images/ in localhost  :

- What modifications should i add to this php script so i could add a folder for each id ( i want to post different images with the same Id in the same folder )

Below is the php file for uploading images :

```
<?php 
$name=$_POST["id"];
$image=$_POST["image"];
$decodedImage=base64_decode("$image");
file_put_contents("images/" . $name . "/" .$name . ".JPG" , $decodedImage);
?>
```

- is there any other way to add multiple images without Repeating the java code many times ?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that directory exists before uploading file to it.

```
$name=$_POST["id"];
$image=$_POST["image"];

if(!file_exists ( "images/" . $name )){
       mkdir("images/" . $name, 755);
}

$decodedImage=base64_decode("$image");
file_put_contents("images/" . $name . "/" .$name . ".JPG" , $decodedImage);
```